# How do I add a background image for a div container?

Tags: python, django, web, jinja2

So I am having a bit of trouble inserting an image inside of a div container. At the top of my page I have a fixed navbar and, underneath the navbar, I have a jumbotron div with a div container with the name of the company as well as the tagline. Instead of there being a bg color for the div jumbotron/div container, I would like there to be an image instead that relates to the services and products that are being provided.

I am using Python Django to create the site and thus am using Jinja to implement static files such as images. Below is the code that I've used that does not work. I would like to be able to implement the image using this same Jinja method of static files rather than url(path to image here)... help?

```
<div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container" style="background-image:{% static 'company/img/familypic.jpg' %}"> 
            <center><h2>Whatever Text Here</h2></center>
            <center><h4>Whatever Tagline Here</h4></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `url('{% static 'company/img/familypic.jpg' %}')` for the background-image to show up.

Comment: Thank you, this worked; however, the image is repeating and I know for a fact that the file size is large enough to span the entire width of the container. How would I make it so that the image expands to fill the entire width of the container? also, the image is large and thus only shows the very top portion of the original image. How do I, for lack of a better term, pan the image down so that a different portion of the image is now viewable? Thank you for your time, patience, and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div class="" style="background-image: url({{ static('company/img/familypic.jpg') }});">
```